# Use [] in ArrayList of ArrayLists java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm creating a hashtable that is a `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> Table = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(size);` 
I want to check if the slot with hash code n is null, using `if(Table [n] == null)`  but ths is wrong. What's wrong with it?

Comment: This should be the correct way to initialise:
       List<List<Integer>> table = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(size);

Comment: 1. Technically you create a list of lists not a hashtable which is a set of key-value pairs.  2. To access list element by index, use `get` (`table[i]` can be applied only to arrays)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access the elements of an ArrayList with the `[...]` syntax. That is only available for arrays. Use

```
if(Table.get(n) == null)
```

instead.

As an unrelated note, make it a habit to follow the Java naming conventions. Variable names should start with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally a hashtable works as follows to insert an item (give or take):

```
int hash = obj.hashCode();
table[hash % table.length].push(obj);
```

You must have a definite length for the table to work correctly and be able to access all positions in the array at any given time. Sure an `ArrayList` can mimic this behavior, but it just makes it slower and under the hood its just a plain old array anyway.

Comment: The OP is probably a student learning how to implement a hashtable.

Comment: Sounds to me like all the more reason not to use built-in Java collections for the table. I think trying to make an `ArrayList` work in this use case will only make the process more difficult later on.